# What's the best way to redeem a Collectors Edition on PS5?

Tags: ps5, horizon-forbidden-west

I preordered the (physical) Collectors Edition of "Horizon: Forbidden West" for my son for Christmas, and it should get here soon. I understand that it doesn't come with a physical disc (which is disappointing, but it is what it is) but with a code instead (which includes bonus content).

My son (who is 12) has his own Sony account (with parental controls) which is part of my family settings and this account is also logged in to the PS5 (but the main account is mine).

Are there any gotchas to look out for when redeeming this game and content? Can I just apply it to my son's account and install it? Or would it be better to apply it to my own account?

Will we both be able to play the game (including bonus content) as long as we use the same PS5?

Comment: And welcome to Arqade!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering myself for future reference:

Since the game ended up being USK 12, I didn't have any concerns with parental controls, so I decided to apply the codes to my son's account, which worked without any issues.

Additionally, all the content, including the Deluxe Edition and preorder bonus, is available to me as well, at least on the same PS5 console (and I don't have another PS5 to try out what would happen).

Answer (score 5):

The question is if your son has an active parental control on his account. *Horizon Forbidden West* will be rated as PEGI 16, and since he is 12 he won't be able to play it on his own account.

[image]

Probably it's better if you redeem the code on your own account.

Comment: Yes, he has parental controls active. Couldn't I explicitly allow the game? I did for "Ratchett & Clank", which is rated PEGI 12, back when he was 11.

Comment: @JensNeubauer if you could previously, I don't see why it couldn't be done again. Sorry but I don't own a PS5 yet so I can't try this.

Comment: Also correct me if im wrong but if the game is installed on the PS5 anybody can play the game on that PS5. Its not locked to the account that redeemed the code.

Comment: @Fredy31 Yes, installed games are shared. But what about bonus content?